# What are easy fast digestible breakfast before workout?

Tags: weightlifting, diet, workout, breakfast

I'm starting to go to gym in the mornings right after I wake up. I'm always working till failure and I've realized that if I don't eat a good meal before workout, I don't have the energy for a good workout.

Getting to gym takes around 30 minutes. I'm also trying to lose weight, what is recommended?

Answer (score 1):

Training fasted almost always leads to less energy in the gym. Since you are trying to lose weight, make sure that you are tracking your calorie intake daily to ensure that you stay in a calorie deficit.

With the deficit in place, you can eat some fast digesting carbs and protein to give you energy. The old school of thought is that sugar causes you to gain fat, but recent studies have shown that this is not the case as long as you are in a calorie deficit (http://www.bodybuilding.com/content/the-science-of-sugar-and-fat-loss.html).

I'd recommend a combination of fast digesting carbs and a fast digesting protein. For the protein, no question, a whey protein shake will do the trick. For the carbs, you have a choice: fruits, coffee with sugar, Gatorade, your favorite sugary cereal with non-fat milk, etc. You have a lot of choices that can digest rapidly and provide you with more energy in the gym.

Also, you can look into pre workout supplements if you aren't interested in the sugary route. They definitely improve energy levels.

Comment: Is there any good non-whey protein alternatives? How about honey for carbs?

Comment: Honey is good, it's not quite as fast-digesting, but it'll stick work for sure. The fastest digesting proteins will be in the form of powders, so you can look at egg or soy. Casein isn't a good option, it digest very slowly.